# How to write integration tests for net/http based code?

Tags: testing, go, integration-testing

Here is an example code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello, world!"))
}

func Router() *http.ServeMux {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", Home)
    return mux
}

func main() {
    mux := Router()
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
}
```

This is the test case I wrote:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestMain(t *testing.T) {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
    Router().ServeHTTP(w, r)
    if w.Body.String() != "Hello, world!" {
        t.Error("Wrong content:", w.Body.String())
    }
}
```

Is this test really sending an HTTP request through a TCP socket and reaching the end point `/`? Or this is just calling the function without making an HTTP connection?

**Update**

Based on the answer given by @ffk I wrote the test like this:

```
func TestMain(t *testing.T) {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(Router())
    defer ts.Close()
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", ts.URL+"/", nil)
    client := http.Client{}
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if string(body) != "Hello, world!" {
        t.Error("Wrong content:", string(body))
    }
}
```

Comment: Your two questions in your text don't really match the title of the question.

Comment: @inf I am looking forward to write integration tests in Go with `net/http`. The above given code is what I am planning to take as the base. With the last two questions I was trying to explain the key integration that I need to test. Do you have any suggestion to improve title or the last two questions?

Comment: Your example test is not making an actual http request. `httptest.NewRecorder()` is just creating an implementation of `http.ResponseWriter` that lets you record what your http handler wrote. This is a fine approach to test http routes. The alternative is actually building and running your code while making actual http requests from your tests.

Comment: @jmaloney Thanks for your suggestion. I will continue this approach as it looks easier to write.

Comment: And don't forget to check errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to instantiate a test server accessible over a random tcp port on 127.0.0.1, use the following:

```
httpHandler := getHttpHandler() // of type http.Handler
testServer := httptest.NewServer(httpHandler)
defer testServer.Close()
request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", testServer.URL+"/my/url", nil)
client := http.Client{}
response, err := client.Do(request)
```

For more info, see https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewServer